# Finding marginal PDFs from a joint PDF using moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

$$CDF: F_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1 - e^{-x} - e^{-y} + e^{-(x+y+\theta xy)}\tag{x > 0 , y > 0}$$

Given the above $CDF$, I'm trying to find the marginal $PDFs$. However, the question states I must work solely from the joint $PDF$ (which I obtained by differentiating the joint $CDF$ w.r.t $x$ and $y$). Doing so gives:

$$PDF: f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \theta(x+y+\theta xy)e^{-(x+y+\theta xy)}-\theta e^{-(x+y+\theta xy)} + e^{-(x+y+\theta xy)}$$

The question states to 'match patterns' to moments from common distributions to determine the marginals and must NOT use integration by parts.

That is,

$$f_{X}(x) = \int_0^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$
$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_0^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$

It also gives that $\theta$ must be contained in $[0,1]$ although I am uncertain as to why...

I've been looking specifically to try and match patterns from exponential moments as the marginal $CDFs$ are exponential $CDFs$:

$$F_X(x)=\lim_{y\to +\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)=1-e^{-x}$$
$$F_Y(y)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)=1-e^{-y}$$

$Q$: How do we determine the marginal PDFs and why must $\theta$ be in $[0,1]$?

Comment: How do you define $F(x,y)$? Is it $P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=F(x,y)$? Then is it $P(X\leq x, Y\leq \infty)=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} F(x,y)=P(X\leq x)$?

Comment: The marginal PDFs should be computed by differentiating $F(x,\infty)$ and $F(\infty,y)$ or by integrating the joint PDF $f$, as explained in the question. The restriction $\theta\leqslant1$ ensures that $F$ is indeed a CDF (otherwise $F$ is not nondecreasing everywhere).